# inx file sample and vs doesnt genrate inf file

Tags: windows, driver, kmdf, inf

I am writing my first kmdf driver and i couldn't understand how do i build my inx/inf file. i saw in microsoft doc that there is supposed to be an inx file sample in the wdf but i couldn't find it. can someone help me find any sample of inx or inf file.
In adition, when i tryed to compile the sample kmdf driver that come with the wdk it generated an inf file for me, but when i tryes to do the same with my driver, it says that there is not any inf file, so i would like to know how can i use visual studio to create the inf file for my project.
Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INX is just INF file that is not being "stamped" (processed by infstamp, to add date, version and etc...)

you can use add INF file to your VS Project (it is just a text file)

I recommend you look at the Microsoft sample of [toaster driver](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/1fe4cc42bedfccb97a5b2cc169f9e5306d41d0de/general/toaster/toastDrv/kmdf/func/simple)